# Meaning of definition of a linear subspace of $\mathrm{P}_2(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathrm{P}_2(x)$, where $W = \{ p(x)\, ; \, p(0) = \alpha p(1) \}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. I know that I have to show that $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, but I'm not quite sure what $p(0) = \alpha p(1)$ means. Given that $\mathrm{P}_2(x)$ is all real coefficient polynomials  of order $\le 2$, what kind of polynomials subset is is $W$?

Comment: This is pretty unusual notation for a polynomial ring. Very easy to confuse with common notation for projective space.

Comment: are you sure that the $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ is *within* the $\{\ldots\}$ and not a parameter?

Comment: Thank you. I changed the notations to be perfectly consistent with the textbook.

Comment: With $\alpha$ inside the brackets it would just be $\mathbb{P}_2(x)$. Otherwise $W$ are all polynomials $p$, which evaluate to $\alpha$ times $p(1)$ at the point $0$.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette Not quite. With $\alpha$ inside, polynomials with $p(1)=0$, $p)0)\ne 0$ would not be in $W$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is fixed (the *same* $\alpha$ for every $p \in W$) then you don't have all of $P_2$. For instance you could have $x+1$ (with $\alpha=1/2$) but then you can't have $x+2$.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen can you give please an example of such polynomial where $p(0)=\alpha p(1)$? Or tell me how to construct such polynomials?

Comment: A polynomial of degree two is of the form $p(x)= a + bx + cx ^2$. We have $p(0)=a$ and $p(1)=a+b+c$. The condition to be in $W$ is then $a=\alpha(a+b+c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$p(0) = \alpha p(1)$$
$$\iff c = \alpha(a + b + c)$$

$$\implies W = \big\{ p(x) = ax^2 + bx + \alpha(a + b + c) \big\} $$

To show a set is a subspace, you have to show the 3 following:

> 1. W is non-empty
> 2. W is closed under addition
> 3. W is closed under scalar multiplication.

**W is non-empty**

You usually prove this by showing the $0$ vector of the superspace belongs to the subspace.
In fact,
$$0 = 0x^2 + 0x + 0$$ and $0 = \alpha(0 + 0+ 0)$
$\implies 0 \in W$

**W is closed under scalar multiplication and addition**

Let $p(x)$ and q(x) $\in$ $W$. They satisfy the property of $W$ namely,

- $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = ax^2 + bx + \alpha(a + b + c)$
- $q(x) = dx^2 + ex + f =dx^2 + ex + \alpha(d + e + f)$

Now

$$p(x) + kq(x) = ax^2 + bx + \alpha(a + b + c) + kdx^2 + kex + k\alpha(d + e + f)$$
$$= (a + kd)x^2 + (b + ke)x + \alpha(a + b + c+ kd + ke + kf)$$

Take
$$A = a + kd$$
$$B = b + ke$$
$$C = c + kf$$

$$\implies p(x) + kq(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + \alpha(A + B + C)$$

Thus $p(x) + kq(x) \in W$

You can now conclude W is a subspace of $P_2$